# Reverse differential on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: category-theory, riemannian-geometry, inner-products

Suppose $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are Riemannian manifolds, and suppose $f:M\to N$ is smooth.  Then for $p\in M$, we have the differential $df_p:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$ as a linear operator.
I'm curious if it makes sense to define a "reverse differential" $rf_p:T_{f(p)}N\to T_pM$
such that for any $\xi\in T_pM$ and any $\zeta\in T_{f(p)}N$ the following equality holds
$$g(rf_p(\zeta),\xi)=h(\zeta,df_p(\xi)).$$

This seems to me to be one natural way of extending the gradient.  Indeed, if $(N,h)=(\mathbb{R},\delta)$, then we can define the gradient of $f$ at $p$, $\text{grad}(f)_p$ via
$$g(\text{grad}(f)_pp,\xi)=df_p(\xi),$$
for any $\xi\in T_pM$.  If we let $\left.\tau\sim\tau\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{f(p)}=:v$ be the usual identification of $\mathbb{R}$ and $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, then we see that the above definition for the reverse differential results in
\begin{align}
g(rf_p(v),\xi)&=\delta(v,df_p(\xi))\\
&=\tau df_p(\xi)\\
&=\tau g(\text{grad}(f)_p,\xi)\\
&=g(\tau\text{grad}(f)_p,\xi),
\end{align}
and hence that
$$\text{grad}(f)_p = rf_p\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{f(p)}\right).$$

This motivation stems from a reading through [Reverse differential categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07065), and I'm curious if this type of derivative works on arbitrary Riemannian manifolds.  The authors use the category of smooth functions on Euclidean space as an example, which leads me to believe that any finite-dimensional, inner product space could handle this definition.  This in turn has to led me to the (semi-?)Riemannian setting.  However, I feel that this would be found somewhere in the literature already, and I haven't been able to find any such sources dealing with this "reverse differential" in this setting.

Comment: One word of caution: do not use $\nabla f_p$ to denote the element of $T_pM$ as the gradient vector, because this very nicely conflicts with the standard differential geometry convention for the covariant derivative, where $\nabla f_p=df_p\in T_p^*M$. I'd much rather use $(\text{grad}_gf) (p)$ to denote this guy (even though $\nabla f_p$ is what is always used in multivariable calculus courses).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I agree on the notation (well the $g$-dependence should be clear from context), I was just being lazy when I posted this.  I've edited the post with the change in notation.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the adjoint of a linear map between different inner product spaces. Let $(V_i,g_i)$ be inner-product spaces for $i=1,2$, and let $T:V_1\to V_2$ be a linear map. We can always consider the dual map $T':V_2^*\to V_1^*$. But now since we have inner products, we can consider the musical isomorphisms $V_i\cong V_i^*$ induced by the inner products (i.e $g_i^{\flat}:V_i\to V_i^*$, $g_i^{\flat}(x):=g_i(x,\cdot)$, and the inverse is denoted $g_i^{\sharp}:V_i^*\to V_i$). Now, we can define the adjoint of $T$ (with respect to $g_1,g_2$) to be the linear map $T^*:V_2\to V_1$,
\begin{align}
T^*:=g_1^{\sharp}\circ T'\circ g_2^{\flat}.
\end{align}
(i.e certain diagram commutes). Conceptually this should make sense: you're given a map $T:V_1\to V_2$, which always induces a mapping between dual spaces in the opposite direction $T':V_2^*\to V_1^*$ (because of how composition works). Using the inner products, we can then force this into a map between the vector spaces themselves rather than their duals.

Then, by unwinding the definitions, you can show that for any $v_1\in V_1, v_2\in V_2$, we have
\begin{align}
g_1(T^*(v_2),v_1)&=g_2(v_2,T(v_1)).
\end{align}
Notice that positive-definiteness of inner products wasn't used, only non-degeneracy so this construction extends to the indefinite case as well. You now just have to apply this idea to each tangent space.

---

The standard use of the adjoint of a linear map consists of using a single inner product space so for $T:V\to V$, we get a map $T^*:V\to V$ such that for all $x,y\in V$, $\langle T(x),y\rangle=\langle x, T^*(y)\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, yes it seems fairly clear that this construction is well-defined in this setting.  I'm just surprised that I haven't found any use/applications in the literature.

Comment: This comes up when defining Laplacian differential operators as the composition of the forward and reverse differential.

Comment: See also Hodge theory, variations on which are definitely on the applied math radar, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05379

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Isn't that the codifferential in this setting, i.e., $d^*$, as apposed to $df^*$ for some smooth $f$?

Comment: Indeed I was referring to the codifferential also arising as an adjoint.